# How do I get the Rails application name within a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to write a Rails 3 `rake` task to generate `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`. I want to pull the application's name instead of hard-coding it in the rake task, but `@app_name` is not yet populated, nor is `ENV['APP_NAME']`. Here's the task's code:

```
desc "Regenerate the server secret"
task :generate_secret do
    include ActiveSupport
    File.open('config/initializers/secret_token.rb', 'w') do |f|
        f.puts "#{@app_name}::Application.config.secret_token = '#{SecureRandom.hex(30)}'"
    end
end
```

It all works except that `@app_name` is blank. How can I retrieve the application name here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the environment in the rake task.  Then you can use `Rails.application.class.parent_name`

```
desc "Regenerate the server secret"
task :generate_secret => :environment do
  include ActiveSupport
  File.open('config/initializers/secret_token.rb', 'w') do |f|
    f.puts "#{Rails.application.class.parent_name}::Application.config.secret_token = '#{SecureRandom.hex(30)}'"
  end
end
```

Comment: When I require `:environment`, I get an error: "(my app name) is not a class/module". A trace shows: ** Invoke bootstrap:generate_secret (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!

Comment: ...and I don't know why, because I've got another task in that .rake file that requires `:environment` and it works fine.

Comment: ...and now, after toying around with it, suddenly it works fine. The magic has a gremlin in it (does rake cache anything when running these tasks?), but it seems to be working now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

**name of the Rails app as it was spelled when you did a "rails new your-app-name"**

```
app_name = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key].sub(/^_/,'').sub(/_session/,'')
=> 'your-app-name'
```

This works very reliable, even if the app directory gets renamed during deployment, and you don't have to take a guess on how to get from the Class name to the correct spelling that was used during 'rails new'.

Using this, you could do this:

```
class << Rails.application
  def name
    Rails.application.config.session_options[:key].sub(/^_/,'').sub(/_session/,'')
  end
end

Rails.application.name
=> 'test-app'
```